# How to render the phrase "to do a reading" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

If I want to say "I do a reading," how would I render that in Latin?

"Ago legendum" or "Legere legendum"
Can I do it using a participle?

"Ago lectionem"
Can I use the word for a reading like this? If so, what verb do I use to accompany it -- ago?

Comment: As for ecclesiastical Latin, it's perfectly ok to use **lectio** for *a reading*. I don't think there's a difference for classical Latin. Thus, **lectionem ago/-ere** should be ok, but... Why not just **lego/-ere**? Though I see there's a difference in nuisance, it's been argued that specific verbs are more correct than auxiliary verb+noun

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this phrase/in what context do you want to use it? For example, if you mean reading something aloud before an audience, as authors may 'do a reading' from their newest work at a bookstore or some other event, the verb *recito* will suffice.

Comment: @Nickimite: It seems that you need to convert verb "to read" to a noun--"the reading". The gerund! What about "paratus ad legendum" = "prepared for the reading"/ "prepared for the purpose of reading"?

Comment: I'm on board with @Rafael. No need to "do a reading" when you can "read." I tell my students "lege + historiam/scaenam/fabulam" instead of circumlocuting.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that an *oratio* is quite regularly *habita* when a “speech is held” in English, I would suggest:

> **Recitationem** (vel lectionem, acroasin, …) **habere**

Google turns up quite a few—but mostly Neo-Latin—hits.